# Sefer recommendations for a couple to learn?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, marriage, chavrusa

I want to start learning with my significant other. Was curious if anyone has any positive experience with a Sefer that would be good for a couple. If so, please recommend!

Comment: Learning with a spouse is not for everyone, so just make sure that you are both on the same page about this. If you are, you might want to discuss the general area that you are interested in learning about, as well as provide relative background - are either (or both) of you fluent in Hebrew? Were you looking to study a basic text in depth, or to "read through" something light together?

Comment: The Manchester RY, R’ Yehuda Zev Segal Ztz”l used to recommend to learn with your wife Sefer Chofetz Chaim

Comment: You should learn Hilchot Ishut 16:19-20

Comment: Impossible to answer without more detail. What is your respective background in learning? Are you interested in halacha? Mussar? Humash commentaries.

Comment: @Alex Why? This seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Michtav Me'Eliyahu (or English version - Strive for Truth). Mesilas Yesharim (available with English translation). Chumash Rashi / Ramban. Tenach. Siddur.

Comment: I know a couple that learn Mesilat Yesharim together.

Comment: Doesn't the implication of the phrase "product *recommendation*" indicate some level of subjectivity? Perhaps the tag needs to be changed to "product" or "product-identification"?

Comment: @Loewian it certainly does and I think it seems reasonable to leave it as is

Comment: @Moderators: If I may ask, how could a product recommendation *not* be opinion-based? How can one use that tag, unless, as mentioned above, it’s merely product identification?

Comment: @michael It's not _primarily_ opinion based when it provides sufficiently specific and objective criteria to evaluate answers' worth. See too https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @michael If you check the Guidance provided to you above in the closure notice you'll find it suggests "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations" and if you click through the link to our Help Center you'll see as well "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 3):

It should go without saying that this question varies greatly for each couple, so I will give some general considerations before my suggestions:

1. Take care to select works accessible to your study partner's level of training with Jewish texts.
2. As with most aspects of relationships, early and clear communication will clear up problems as they arise.
3. Think about what you would each like to get out of the experience: Are you trying to convey the beauty of delving into an esoteric gemara, brush up on your knowledge of Jewish history, come away with moral teachings, etc.

With that being said, the following works have been enjoyable for my wife and me:

- Tomer Devorah (M. Cordovero). A work that encourages us to think about our relationships with others and our relationship with Hashem
- The Sabbath (A.J. Heschel). Uses poetry to foster a love for the unique beauty of Shabbat
- Nineteen Letters (S.R. Hirsch). Brings many of the complexities of reconciling Torah Judaism with modern Enlightenment, and in a powerful, elegant tour de force
- Shaar Ha'Bitachon. A foundational work concerning a Jew's everyday faith in Hashem.

Happy reading!

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, every couple is different so it does require a bit of thought based on where you are both holding.

Secondly, it is worth remembering that your wife is not your yeshiva chavrusa(!). The story is told about a newlywed couple who decided to learn chumash and Rashi together. It was not long before they got into the swing of things, and his wife who suggested a p'shat had it quickly dismissed by the husband who was used to the milchemta shel Torah of yeshiva life and arguing out points with his chavrusa. When the husband noticed his wife had gone quiet, he looked up to see her crying. Needless to say, one has to remember that one's wife is one's ezer kenegdo and should be treated with sensitivity and respect.

I found it helpful to learn things that are relevant to both one's life, so sefarim on inyanei chinuch is definitely a good one. My wife and I particularly enjoyed Rav Wolbe's *Zeriyah Ubinyan b'Chinuch*. It comes in both [Hebrew](https://www.sefer.org.il/Product/48832/%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A---%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%94) and [English](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/planting-building-raising-a-jewish-child/4378)

Another option is to work on something that is Mussar based. As growing Jews we all need help on  the self-improvement front. I recommend [Sefer Orchos Tzaddikim](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim) also available in both [Hebrew](https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/arhvt-cdiqim-em-hervt-vcivnim-mpel-tvrt-hmvsr.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwzOqKBhAWEiwArQGwaFkrqrLAuvEJdObIZo8OmrYhn8Tk2tdhYAYn1nmtxuc7QPjk0PLgihoC2AAQAvD_BwE) and [English](https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/the-ways-of-the-tzaddikim-orchos-tzaddikim-pocket-edition-1-volume.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwzOqKBhAWEiwArQGwaDvLSWAIqe3MohEuCUJAcTeBTlTYiP53Z2i1QQuv3S4IgFmsh-rHthoCh-8QAvD_BwE).

Finally, something on Jewish philosophy / machshava is also quite nice to learn together. I have learnt with my wife Michtav M'Eliyahu and Alei Shur which is also very nice as it looks at all areas of Jewish life.

Comment: Your second paragraph certainly also depends on circumstances. In particular, I know people who have married their yeshiva chavrusa, and although I didn't, I learn with my wife like that.

Answer (score -1):

Hilchos Nidda (esp. harchakot) is a good idea.